# python closest timestamp data identification and grouping

Tags: python, dataframe

I have dataframe with data for every 30 minutes.

```
combined_df =
         datetime         data1 data2 
    2019-01-01 08:00:00     10     20 
    2019-01-01 08:01:00     30     40
   .
   . 
    2019-01-01 08:30:00     100     200
    2019-01-01 08:31:00     300    400
    .
    .
```

Now I want to group the data by closely matching timestamps. In above case, I want to obtain following output:

```
session_df = 
         datetime         data1 data2   data1   data2 
    2019-01-01 08:00:00     10     20    30       40   .  . 
    2019-01-01 08:30:00    100     200   300      400  . . 
    .
    .
```

How to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

the question is a little unclear, I suggest rewording, but I think you are trying to look at the combined_df in 30min chunks, and then combine all the values in data1 and data2 into one row in an alternating fashion, and assign this row to a new df called session_df for each 30min chunk, using the starting time of each chunk as the datetime value

this might work for you, I tested it on some dummy data similar to yours

```
df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']) #convert to datetime, not necessary if already in proper format
df.set_index(['datetime'],inplace=True) #not necessary but I like to keep my dates in the index

final_datetimes=df.index[(df.index.minute==0) | (df.index.minute==30)] #get all datetimes in 30min intervals, starting and 0 and ending at 30
num_cols=2*len(df[(df.index >= final_datetimes[0]) & (df.index < final_datetimes[1])]) #number of columns needed for new df
col_names= ['data' + str(num) for num in range(num_cols)] #generate list of names for them (can't have duplicate column names in df)

df2=pd.DataFrame(index=final_datetimes,columns=col_names) #new df with the datetime intervals and correct number of columns

for row in df2.iterrows(): #iterate through each row
    iloc = df2.index.get_loc(row[0])  # get index location (row[0] is the index value of that row)
    data1_list = df[(df.index >= df2.index[iloc]) & (df.index < df2.index[iloc+1])]['data1'].values.tolist() #get all data1 values in this range
    data2_list = df[(df.index >= df2.index[iloc]) & (df.index < df2.index[iloc+1])]['data2'].values.tolist() #get all data2 values in this range
    final_list = [None]*len(data1_list+data2_list) #create empty list of correct size to store all data1 and data2 values
    final_list[::2],final_list[1::2] = data1_list,data2_list #populate list with data1 and data2 values in alternating order
    df2.iloc[iloc]=final_list #assign list to all columns in row
```

NOTE - you will have to add an if statement (or slightly modify code) to handle the last step as there is no bounding next datetime to combine data from

Comment: Derek Eden The data might not differ exactly by 30 minutes or does not start at 8 AM all the day. So, in that case, it may not work.

Comment: the above code doesn't depend on the hour at all, it just splits the data into 30min intervals based on the minutes in the datetime.. it is hard to tell how to group your data if you are not clear about what the data actually contains..if  you know what the min intervals are, you can change that in the code, or you can potentially base it off the minutes of the first timestamp

Comment: if you are trying to combine data for which the datetime has no gaps (i.e. each data point is 1min apart) then you can look for datetimes for which the following datetime is more than 1min away..it's still not clear exactly what you are trying to do